# R: Creating a Data Frame from "Loose" Data

Tags: r, formatting, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose you have the following "loose" data:

```
  weight   height age
                      1  2998.958 15.26611  53
                      2  3002.208 18.08711  52
                      3  3008.171 16.70896  49
                      4  3002.374 17.37032  55
                      5  3000.658 18.04860  50
                      6  3002.688 17.24797  45
                      7  3004.923 16.45360  47
                      8  2987.264 16.71712  47
                      9  3011.332 17.76626  50
                      10 2983.783 18.10337  42
                      11 3007.167 18.18355  50
                      12 3007.049 18.11375  53
                      13 3002.656 15.49990  42
                      14 2986.710 16.73089  47
                      15 2998.286 17.12075  52
```

You can make this into a data frame using the following command:

```
    my_data <- data.frame(read.table(header=TRUE,
    row.names = 1,
    text="
                             weight   height age
                          1  2998.958 15.26611  53
                          2  3002.208 18.08711  52
                          3  3008.171 16.70896  49
                          4  3002.374 17.37032  55
                          5  3000.658 18.04860  50
                          6  3002.688 17.24797  45
                          7  3004.923 16.45360  47
                          8  2987.264 16.71712  47
                          9  3011.332 17.76626  50
                          10 2983.783 18.10337  42
                          11 3007.167 18.18355  50
                          12 3007.049 18.11375  53
                          13 3002.656 15.49990  42
                          14 2986.710 16.73089  47
                          15 2998.286 17.12075  52
    "))

#view results

head(my_data)
    weight   height age
1 2998.958 15.26611  53
2 3002.208 18.08711  52
3 3008.171 16.70896  49
4 3002.374 17.37032  55
5 3000.658 18.04860  50
6 3002.688 17.24797  45
```

**My Question:** Suppose I have the following loose data:

```
#data 1  (10 rows x 10 columns)

   num_var_1 num_var_2  num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2    factor_var_3             factor_var_4             factor_var_5
1   8.251683 27.791314  30.525573  33.95768   2.388074            B         <NA>             AAA                     AAAA                     DDDD
2   9.012602        NA         NA        NA  20.236515            A        AA BB            <NA>                     <NA>                     BBBB
3         NA 16.778085  28.097324   5.69020         NA            B           BB     CCC DDD DDD                     <NA> AAAA BBBB CCCC CCCC CCCC
4  12.838667 -3.694075  13.411877  -2.20004         NA         <NA>     AA AA BB     AAA BBB CCC                     <NA> AAAA AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
5         NA        NA  11.922439  17.63757         NA          A B     AA AA BB            <NA>                AAAA AAAA                     BBBB
6  12.768595        NA  28.507646        NA         NA            C           AA     BBB DDD DDD      AAAA AAAA CCCC DDDD AAAA AAAA BBBB EEEE EEEE
7         NA        NA -20.424906        NA  20.147004         <NA>        AA AA            <NA> AAAA AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE                     <NA>
8         NA  6.299722   8.569485  24.82825 -17.715862         <NA>           BB AAA AAA BBB CCC                     <NA>                BBBB EEEE
9  10.846757        NA         NA        NA         NA        A B C     AA BB CC            <NA>                     <NA>                BBBB BBBB
10        NA  4.663916  22.335404        NA         NA        B B C        AA BB AAA AAA AAA DDD AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE EEEE                     <NA>

#data 2 (10 rows x 2 columns)

   iteration                                                                                                                                                                                        results
          1                                                                                                                                                 num_var_5 > 29.80, factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC"
          2         num_var_1 < 8.44, num_var_4 > 37.01, factor_var_1 = "A, B, C", factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC", factor_var_3 = "DDD", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, DDDD", factor_var_5 = "BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          3                                               num_var_1 < 9.70, num_var_2 < 19.75, num_var_3 < 35.03, num_var_4 > 20.12, num_var_5 < -6.67, factor_var_2 = "AA, BB", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB"
          4                                                                                         num_var_4 > 31.51, num_var_5 < 4.49, factor_var_1 = "C", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          5                                                                                     num_var_4 < 23.87, factor_var_2 = "AA", factor_var_3 = "AAA, DDD", factor_var_5 = "AAAA, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          6                                                                                                                                     num_var_4 < 18.07, factor_var_5 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"
          7                                                                                                      num_var_3 < 9.19, num_var_4 < 13.21, num_var_5 < 14.59, factor_var_4 = "BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"
          8 num_var_1 > 11.07, num_var_3 > 8.17, num_var_4 < 23.00, num_var_5 < 35.93, factor_var_2 = "AA", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, DDD", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, BBBB, EEEE", factor_var_5 = "CCCC, EEEE"
          9                                                                               num_var_1 < 10.77, num_var_2 > 24.95, num_var_3 > 4.78, factor_var_2 = "CC", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD"
        10                                                                                      num_var_2 > 2.65, factor_var_1 = "B, C", factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD"
```

I can't seem to make these into data frames:

```
data_1 <- data.frame(read.table(header=TRUE,
                                 row.names = 1,
                                 text="
                          num_var_1 num_var_2  num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2    factor_var_3             factor_var_4             factor_var_5
1   8.251683 27.791314  30.525573  33.95768   2.388074            B         <NA>             AAA                     AAAA                     DDDD
2   9.012602        NA         NA        NA  20.236515            A        AA BB            <NA>                     <NA>                     BBBB
3         NA 16.778085  28.097324   5.69020         NA            B           BB     CCC DDD DDD                     <NA> AAAA BBBB CCCC CCCC CCCC
4  12.838667 -3.694075  13.411877  -2.20004         NA         <NA>     AA AA BB     AAA BBB CCC                     <NA> AAAA AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
5         NA        NA  11.922439  17.63757         NA          A B     AA AA BB            <NA>                AAAA AAAA                     BBBB
6  12.768595        NA  28.507646        NA         NA            C           AA     BBB DDD DDD      AAAA AAAA CCCC DDDD AAAA AAAA BBBB EEEE EEEE
7         NA        NA -20.424906        NA  20.147004         <NA>        AA AA            <NA> AAAA AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE                     <NA>
8         NA  6.299722   8.569485  24.82825 -17.715862         <NA>           BB AAA AAA BBB CCC                     <NA>                BBBB EEEE
9  10.846757        NA         NA        NA         NA        A B C     AA BB CC            <NA>                     <NA>                BBBB BBBB
10        NA  4.663916  22.335404        NA         NA        B B C        AA BB AAA AAA AAA DDD AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE EEEE                     <NA>
"))

Error in read.table(header = TRUE, row.names = 1, text = "\n                          num_var_1 num_var_2  num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2    factor_var_3             factor_var_4             factor_var_5\n1   8.251683 27.791314  30.525573  33.95768   2.388074            B         <NA>             AAA                     AAAA                     DDDD\n2   9.012602        NA         NA        NA  20.236515            A        AA BB            <NA>                     <NA>                     BBBB\n3         NA 16.778085  28.097324   5.69020         NA            B           BB     CCC DDD DDD                     <NA> AAAA BBBB CCCC CCCC CCCC\n4  12.838667 -3.694075  13.411877  -2.20004         NA         <NA>     AA AA BB     AAA BBB CCC                     <NA> AAAA AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD\n5         NA        NA  11.922439  17.63757         NA          A B     AA AA BB            <NA>                AAAA AAAA                     BBBB\n6  12.768595        NA  28.507646        NA         NA            C           AA     BBB DDD DDD      AAAA AAAA CCCC DDDD AAAA AAAA BBBB EEEE EEEE\n7         NA        NA -20.424906        NA  20.147004         <NA>        AA AA            <NA> AAAA AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE                     <NA>\n8         NA  6.299722   8.569485  24.82825 -17.715862         <NA>           BB AAA AAA BBB CCC                     <NA>                BBBB EEEE\n9  10.846757        NA         NA        NA         NA        A B C     AA BB CC            <NA>                     <NA>                BBBB BBBB\n10        NA  4.663916  22.335404        NA         NA        B B C        AA BB AAA AAA AAA DDD AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE EEEE                     <NA>\n") : 
  more columns than column names


data_2 <- data.frame(read.table(header=TRUE,
                           row.names = 1,
                           text="

           iteration                                                                                                                                                                                        results
          1                                                                                                                                                 num_var_5 > 29.80, factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC"
          2         num_var_1 < 8.44, num_var_4 > 37.01, factor_var_1 = "A, B, C", factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC", factor_var_3 = "DDD", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, DDDD", factor_var_5 = "BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          3                                               num_var_1 < 9.70, num_var_2 < 19.75, num_var_3 < 35.03, num_var_4 > 20.12, num_var_5 < -6.67, factor_var_2 = "AA, BB", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB"
          4                                                                                         num_var_4 > 31.51, num_var_5 < 4.49, factor_var_1 = "C", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          5                                                                                     num_var_4 < 23.87, factor_var_2 = "AA", factor_var_3 = "AAA, DDD", factor_var_5 = "AAAA, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          6                                                                                                                                     num_var_4 < 18.07, factor_var_5 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"
          7                                                                                                      num_var_3 < 9.19, num_var_4 < 13.21, num_var_5 < 14.59, factor_var_4 = "BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"
          8 num_var_1 > 11.07, num_var_3 > 8.17, num_var_4 < 23.00, num_var_5 < 35.93, factor_var_2 = "AA", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, DDD", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, BBBB, EEEE", factor_var_5 = "CCCC, EEEE"
          9                                                                               num_var_1 < 10.77, num_var_2 > 24.95, num_var_3 > 4.78, factor_var_2 = "CC", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD"
        10                                                                                      num_var_2 > 2.65, factor_var_1 = "B, C", factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD"

                     
"

))

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                                                      results
          1                                                                                                                                                 num_var_5 > 29.80, factor_var_2 = "A"
>           2         num_var_1 < 8.44, num_var_4 > 37.01, factor_var_1 = "A, B, C", factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC", factor_var_3 = "DDD", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, DDDD", factor_var_5 = "BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
Error: unexpected symbol in "          2         num_var_1"
>           3                                               num_var_1 < 9.70, num_var_2 < 19.75, num_var_3 < 35.03, num_var_4 > 20.12, num_var_5 < -6.67, factor_var_2 = "AA, BB", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB"
Error: unexpected symbol in "          3                                               num_var_1"
>           4                                                                                         num_var_4 > 31.51, num_var_5 < 4.49, factor_var_1 = "C", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
Error: unexpected symbol in "          4                                                                                         num_var_4"
>           5                                                                                     num_var_4 < 23.87, factor_var_2 = "AA", factor_var_3 = "AAA, DDD", factor_var_5 = "AAAA, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
Error: unexpected symbol in "          5                                                                                     num_var_4"
>           6                                                                                                                                     num_var_4 < 18.07, factor_var_5 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"
Error: unexpected symbol in "          6                                                                                                                                     num_var_4"
>           7                                                                                                      num_var_3 < 9.19, num_var_4 < 13.21, num_var_5 < 14.59, factor_var_4 = "BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"
Error: unexpected symbol in "          7                                                                                                      num_var_3"
>           8 num_var_1 > 11.07, num_var_3 > 8.17, num_var_4 < 23.00, num_var_5 < 35.93, factor_var_2 = "AA", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, DDD", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, BBBB, EEEE", factor_var_5 = "CCCC, EEEE"
Error: unexpected symbol in "          8 num_var_1"
>           9                                                                               num_var_1 < 10.77, num_var_2 > 24.95, num_var_3 > 4.78, factor_var_2 = "CC", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD"
Error: unexpected symbol in "          9                                                                               num_var_1"
>         10                                                                                      num_var_2 > 2.65, factor_var_1 = "B, C", factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD"
Error: unexpected symbol in "        10                                                                                      num_var_2"
> 
>                      
> "
+ 
+ ))
+
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of showing your data as a table, please post your dput(). You can use this code and copy and paste the results -- head(df) %>% dput()

Comment: @ OTA: Thank you for your reply! I am not sure I understood your comment, can you please explain it again? Thank you!

Comment: Sure. Take a look at this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/251y3ms

Comment: head(df) %>% dput() gives the output ---->  structure(list(age = c(20, 30)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

Comment: @ OTA: Thank you for your reply! This is very useful!

Comment: But what if the data appears just like this: https://imgur.com/a/vprKA4V

Comment: Suppose the data was "loose" and was just floating around on a website? suppose the data is not already contained in a data frame? can it still be used with the "dput()" command? thanks!

Comment: Probably not. You would likely need to make mini example dataframes of your examples then.

Comment: @stats555 The main problem are the additional spaces in the columns. In the first example, there are no spaces within a column, so each column can easily be delimited. However, in the other 2 (that had errors), there are spaces within the columns, so it delimits a column between each character set (e.g., `AAAA BBBB`), but there are less column names than how many columns it's trying to create (hence the error). It does work if commas are added in between (e.g., `AAAA, BBBB`). But I'm not sure how you would code those in (or if that's even possible in this context).